# Need help or idea on how to setup a Drupal site on a given scenario

Tags: views

I need ideas/help on how to setup a drupal website with following given scenario. I just come up with the scenario this is not real but if I get the answers then I think I can apply on real poject.

I have two content-type **Movies** & **Celebrities**.

Movies content type will list all the movies information like...
"Movie story overview", "movie review" and "movie cast"

Similarly I have Celebrities content type which will Celeb information like
Movies acted, Bio, awards etc.

Now what I want...

**First Objective:**

- When I add a new celebrities node to site, how can I create/add multiple pages automatically
  Example: I added a new celebrity named “kate winslet” by using “Add Content”->Celebrities content type. Now when I save it there should be 4 urls created in one go.

  a.   Domain.com/celebrity/kate-winslet
     b.   Domain.com/celebrity/kate-winslet /movies-acted
     c.   Domain.com/celebrity/kate-winslet /bio
     d.   Domain.com/celebrity/kate-winslet /awards

Similarly while adding a Movies content type it should generate multiple pages like

- a.   Domain.com/movies/titanic/overview
- b.  Domain.com/movies/titanic/cast
- c. And more like this.

Note: I don’t want to create pages manually. Only one main landing page for each type should be created manually and rest of the pages should be added itself.

Now...

**Second Objective:**

- On the “domain.com/movies/titanic/cast” page, how can I have functionality to look-up all the celebrities page titles & url and link both, a movie with its casts or an actor/actress with movies.

**Example:** I added a new movie “titanic”, now the movies content type may have a custom filed (CCK) named as “movie cast” where I will be adding actor/actress full name like “kate winslet”, “leonardo dicaprio” etc.

Now what I want is these names should be link to their corresponding celebrity pages like

a.  “kate winslet” shoule be linked to Domain.com/celebrity/kate-winslet

b.  And “leonardo dicaprio” should be linked to Domain.com/celebrity/ Leonardo-dicaprio

Any idea or help is highly appreciated.

Comment: the first objective can be done with views by setting filter criteria/parameters (that look into the url for the parameters). filter on celebrity-name , filter on celebrity-name and movies-acted , ... This way you only create one page, but limit what is shown through views.

Comment: It is difficult to answer a "not real" question because there is no way to verify answers. Instead, please consider the real project; is there something blocking you or making it not work? Post the specific blockage or show us what isn't working. Thought experiments too easily degenerate into polls or ambiguous answers with no way of telling what is right or wrong.

Comment: Its a travel website concept and pretty much very similar to the scenario given in the question. I was planning the structure and as of now every thing is on paper like a blueprint. Even if I put the real project here it will be lots of confusion so I though extracting the challenging part here and shared with community for some advice.

Comment: @Jozzeh : Thanks for the idea, I did try the same way using views. its giving me node number in the url like celebrity/20/bio,  but I guess this is not a big deal this can be resolved by pathauto. Only issue I am looking here is content of the bio page will just be a CCK field and this limits me with content of the Bio page. I want this to be a full node. But this actually gave me something to start with. I guess I need little more testings. :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the second objective instead of adding the actors to the movie, since you already are going to add movie appearances to each actor, make those movies taxonomy terms.  Then when you want to make a cast page for a movie, just display all of the actors that have that taxonomy term (the movie name) associated with it.